# mvn could not find or load main class org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.launcher

Tags: java, maven, cmd

I know there are many posts about this topic and I already tried to fix it by adding, editing and deleting the system variables.

My variables are the following:

`M2_Home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0 (I already tried it with \bin didn't work ether.)`

`JAVA_Home: C:\Users\haa\Desktop\jdk1.8.0_101`

`Path:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\CCM;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Users\haa\Desktop\ARA_STUFF\apache-maven-3.5.0\apache-maven\src\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%systemroot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;%JAVA_HOME%`

Does anyone know what I could try to fix this issue?

Comment: Windows 7 is my os btw.

Comment: I already tried to change the M2_Home to M3_HOME didn't work either

Comment: I also tried to redownload the bin file and reinstalled java and idk what else I could do

Comment: Remove M2_HOME, MAVEN_HOME etc. from your environment. Only use the bin directory into the `PATH`...and of course JAVA_HOME...that's it...

Comment: Well I already tried that, but it is still not working tho.. no idea what to do

Comment: Have closed the console windows and reopened it after the change?

Comment: Yeah when I try to execute a mvn command  the cannot load .. error is displayed